# Select an array in a json response

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel

I have a json response like this:

```
{
    "orders": [
        {
            "position": 0,
            "order": {
                "link": "saudagar_gadget",
                "count": 979,
            }
        },
        {
            "position": 1,
            "order": {
                "link": "admin_wg",
                "count": 289,
            }
        },
        {
            "position": 2,
            "order": {
                "link": "admin.wg_shop",
                "count": 200,
            }
        },
    ],
}
```

When a user picks a link, I want to search the links in the response, then extract the desired order accordingly and then display the count of that order.

How can I do this search? With which `php` function?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you would do it

```php
Route::get('{link}', function () {
    $link = request('link'); // Get the desired link from the request url
    // Decode the json to an array
    $array = json_decode('{
        "orders": [
            {
                "position": 0,
                "order": {
                    "link": "saudagar_gadget",
                    "count": 979
                }
            },
            {
                "position": 1,
                "order": {
                    "link": "admin_wg",
                    "count": 289
                }
            },
            {
                "position": 2,
                "order": {
                    "link": "admin.wg_shop",
                    "count": 200
                }
            }
        ]
    }');
    // Since we're using Laravel, collect the array orders to expose useful collection methods
    $orders = collect($array->orders);
    // Query the collection by a where clause matching the order's link by the request parameter
    return $orders->where('order.link', $link)->first()->order->count; // Get the first result and access its values by object notation
});
```

Result: `200`

Comment: I received `Method get does not exist.` error for  `Route::get('{link}', function ()`

Comment: This was just an example, don't just copy paste everything, use it in your controller method depending on the rest of your code